# Как узнать характеристики ПК средствами .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли возможность средствами .NET узнать характеристики ПК( допустим для процессора: его название, частота, количество ядер и тд.)?

Comment: Инструкция CPUID вам определенно поможет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы что, издеваетесь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот отличный пример как это сделать.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Comment: Действительно, хороший пример. Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите пример здесь, ответ--ссылка не приветствуется